# Can't input two char array in c++ continuously

Tags: c++

It is skipping the second array to take input.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a[5],b[5];
    cout<<"Enter a : ";
    cin.get(a,5)
    cout<<"Enter b : ";
    cin.get(b,5);
    cout<<"Done";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a : "abc"
Enter b :
Done
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Your example is not complete, since [it works for me](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ki6sDYsYVzmpk5C9) (after small fixes). Also you have mixedup output with input, since your code doesn't print `a` or `b`.

Comment: @MarekR I could reproduce the issue of OP: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76484d3da2ff2ca4) (Yes, I added the missing `;`.) ;-) The reason is that I used the input like exposed by OP: `abc` and ENTER. After reading a bit clue-less in [std::istream::get()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) I realized that `\n` is detected but **not extracted**. _the next available input character c equals delim, as determined by Traits::eq(c, delim). This character is not extracted (unlike basic_istream::getline())_ This needs extra handling...

Comment: Hey @Scheff, it looks like you wrote an answer in a comment ;)

Comment: @ypnos I would consider that an answer if I would have elaborated _This needs extra handling..._ But actually, I wouldn't use neither char arrays nor `get()` to read them (in this case).

Comment: It is due to keyboard buffer . When you insert character and press enter the \n is placed at the end and the second input do not wait for user and takes \n as entered input . So it skipped. You need to flush the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is minimal complete verifiable example which reproduces your issue.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a[5], b[5];

    cin.get(a, 5);
    cin.get(b, 5);

    cout << "a = " << a << '\n';
    cout << "b = " << b << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/NonDLZiDhaIyKff4

Now you should start from reading documentation:

[std::basic_istream::get - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)

> - the next available input character `c` equals `delim`, as determined by Traits::eq(c, delim). This character is **not extracted** (unlike [basic_istream::getline()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline))

so problem is delimiter.

It would be best if you write code which is more C++ and use such code (not like C code):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a, b;

    std::getline(cin, a);
    std::getline(cin, b);

    cout << "a = " << a << '\n';
    cout << "b = " << b << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/iWcHo2jpVHKdnIJy

Comment: There are valid reasons to want a stack-allocated string. Especially considering OP only wanted to read the first 5 characters, I don't think your code does what OP wanted.

Comment: Small string optimization does that silently. I recommend to use `std::string` as good practice ([this is why](https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk)). Also doc says to use [basic_istream::getline()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) instead `get` to discard delimiter.